# How to print just a few from an array instead of all in php

Tags: php, arrays, random, shuffle

This is part of the working code that shows the entire array;

```
$files = filelist("./",1,1); // call the function
shuffle($files);
foreach ($files as $list) {//print array
echo "<a href=\"" . $list['name'] . "$startDir\"><h4> " . $list['name'] . " </h4></a>";
//    echo "Directory: " . $list['dir'] . " => Level: " . $list['level'] . " => Name: " . $list['name'] . " => Path: " . $list['path'] ."<br>";
```

How do I modify it so that it only displays 10 or 15 list instead of all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a counter to limit the number of iterations:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($files as $list) {//print array
    // your loop code here...
    $counter++;
    if ($counter > 10) break;
}
```

Comment: Use `break` wisely: If you have much code in `// your loop code here...` the `if($foo) break;` gets out of sight quite fast. Have a look at Starx code: It has even 3 lines less to keep track of the iteration variable ;)

Comment: @KingCrunch the problem with Starx code is: in php there is no difference between "lists" and "maps", so you can have an array like ``array(10=>'a', 11=>'b', 12=>'c')``, in which case the first element has key ``10`` instead of ``0``..
Furthermore, you'd also have to use ``$i<min(10, count($files))`` to avoid iterating over non-existent items in case ``$files`` have less than 10 items..

Comment: @redShadow A minor addition: `for ($i = 0, $count = min(15, count($files); $i < $count; $i++)` is better. OK, it's a kind of micro-optimization too, but just avoid function calls in the test-expression :) If you are unsure about the keys of an array, use `array_values()` (or use `array_keys()` to iterate over the keys instead), but I don't think thats an issue here :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the keys or indexes of the array you can do what KingCrunch is doing a lot faster by simple for loop

```
for($i=0; $i<=14; $i++) {
   // echo $file[$i];
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an proof for "a lot faster"?

Comment: @KingCrunch, Try it! Even with simple thought it avoids the needs to go through `array_slice()`

Comment: This comment tells me, that you can't proof it. That it is an additional function call, doesn't mean, that it cause a siginificant/feelable performance impact.

Comment: "A lot faster", thanks for making me laugh out load on this really, really quiet train.

Comment: @KingCrunch, Or larger array it will make difference, see [this](http://codepad.org/1qG37V8z) make be it will give you some idea.

Comment: @Starx You try to proof your code with an example, that proofs, that I am right? The difference is around 11% (The usual "I feel it" barrier is around 20%) and we are talking about durations < 1 ns. To make it more interesting: Here is the same example with 1 million entries http://codepad.org/qgJFIjb3 As you can see there is no real difference to your test. So in your opinion a difference of 0.15ns is "a lot faster"?

Answer (score -2):

There is a function for it

```
foreach(array_slice($files, 0, 15) as $file) { 
  /* your code here */ 
}
```

http://php.net/array-slice

Another solution is to use `array_rand()` instead of `shuffle()` and `array_chunk()`

```
foreach (array_rand($files, 15) as $key) {
  $file = $files[$key];
  // Your code here
 }
```

http://php.net/array-rand

Note, that this keeps the order of the keys (see salathes comment below).

Comment: `array_rand()` preserves the original array order (as of PHP 5.2.10), which is probably not what the OP wants (since they're already using `shuffle()`).

Comment: `array_slice()` creates another array of (n) length, when he already has a properly sorted array he can just pop the first 15 from.

Comment: @salathe You could shuffle the keys ;) But I see the point. Added it as a notice in the answer

Comment: @TimPost Pop the first elements changes the original array. As long as this is not wanted (for example because it should behave like a queue, or stack) you should avoid it. And avoiding the creation of new arrays "just because" is kind of micro-optimization.

Comment: @KingCrunch Well, or just read instead of pop, but fair enough :)

Comment: @TimPost Like in Starxs answer (beside, that I don't share the "a lot faster" :D), so no need to duplicate it here ;) I stillt don't think my solution as any _noticable_ downside and it works, so I don't get the problem ^^